# Change a Function by Editing its Binary in Linux

Tags: linux, function, replace, binary, editing

I am looking to edit a binary file to replace one function by another function in Linux.
For eg.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int test(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
main()
{
    int c=test(3,2);
    printf("%d\n",c);
}
```

I want to change the function test() to something else, say multiply editing just the binary file.
Can someone please guide me on how to edit the binary file to replace a function in linux (Debian) ?

Comment: Use some linux hex editor with builtin disassembler. Some are listed [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Analysis_Tools). For more comfort, try to find hex editor with builtin assembler too, for example http://hte.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [here](http://www.linuxsa.org.au/meetings/reveng-0.2.pdf) to get a idea of reverse engineering a elf binary.